# why are there so few simultaneous requests in Locust?

Tags: python, stress-testing

Why are there 2 requests on average if I spawn 100 users simultaneously? Shouldn't there be 100 simultaneous requests at the beginning? What may be the reason that does not happen?

I have set up a very simple stress test in Locust, with a user class that does a post on an API.

I spawn 100 users at a rate of 100 per second so they spawn as fast as they can (takes about 2 seconds to spawn all the users). Why aren't there 100 http calls within the first 2 to 10 seconds? What's going on?

[image: average http calls per second on Locust]

Answer (score 1):

100 users means up to 100 concurrent requests.

The actual number of requests per second is dependant on a lot of things (response times of the server, wait times in your test etc), so there is only an indirect relationship between the number of users and the number of requests per second.

For a full explanation and possible solutions, see https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps

Btw, most locust questions are on stackoverflow.